# How can i see highest voted "Community-wiki" questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, community-wiki, voting

As of now i can see highest voted questions based on tags,search/simply `Questions--->Votes` etc..... But can i see highest voted "**Community-wiki**" questions? Any suggestion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for `wiki:1` and order by votes?

You might want to read the [Search Options page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search).

That seems to get answers too, so add a "questions" qualifier like `wiki:1 views:1000`.

- For [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki%3a1%20views%3a100&tab=votes)
- For [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=wiki%3a1%20views%3a1000&tab=votes)
- For [Super User](https://superuser.com/search?q=wiki%3a1%20views%3a1000&tab=votes)
- For [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki%3a1%20views%3a1000&tab=votes)